# Grails Fixtures Plugin: How do I clean up fixtures after every integration test in Grails?

Tags: grails, integration-testing, grails-2.3

I want all the fixtures I've created for one test to be removed once it's done to keep my tests isolated. Is there a way to iterate over the `fixture` object and delete the GORM objects that are persisted?